# Finding IP in command line

Tags: windows, command-line

Is it possible to find only the connected IP address of my device in command line by leaving the other adapters. I have used ipconfig, ipconfig /all but it displays all the adapters with the media state as Disconnected. 
   I want to display only the media connected IP address in command line. Is there any way for windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "items="
SET "notitems="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('ipconfig') DO SET "line=%%a"&CALL :record
SET "line="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('ipconfig') DO (
 ECHO :%items%:|FIND ":%%a:" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "line=Y"
 IF DEFINED notitems (
  ECHO :%notitems%:|FIND ":%%a:" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "line="
 )
 IF DEFINED line ECHO %%a
)
GOTO :EOF

:record
:: items begin in col 1 and end with ":"
IF "%line:~0,1%" equ " " GOTO notitem
IF "%line:~-1%" neq ":" GOTO notitem
SET "items=:%line%%items%"
SET "lastitem=%line%"

GOTO :eof

:notitem
IF "%line:~-18%"=="Media disconnected" SET "notitems=:%lastitem%%notitems%"
GOTO :EOF
```

This should show you what you appear to want - an example would have been helpful.

Using `ipconfig` each report for an item begins with `itemname:` starting in the first column.

You appear to wish to suppress `media disconnected` items, so for lines that start with a space (or don't end with `:`, see whether the last 18 characters match the string `Media disconnected`.

Record each string passing the appropriate test in `items` when an item is detected and `notitems` if the item is not to be reported. Surround each with colons, so the result is a colon-delimited list.

Then run through `ipconfig` again. If an item is detected, set `line` to `Y` (so the report will be turned on) but if the item is in the `notitems` list, set `line` (now acting as a report switch) to *nothing*.

Result: reporting will be switched on when an item is detected, and off again when a non-item is detected.

Answer (score 0):

Try `netstat -n`. It gives a list of current connections. You can find the IP address used.

Comment: @bluenick  thanks, but it displays all the connected ip.  I need default gateway, subnet mask, Ipv4 address similar to we get in ipconfig in windows which is the path connected to network.

Answer (score 0):

On **Ubuntu**( and **Debian** like distro)

to see your local IP address:

```
hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'
```

to see your Global IP address:

```
curl -4 icanhazip.com
```

to see all information about your(or any)IP address:

```
 whois $(curl -4 icanhazip.com)
```

assumed you have installed `whois` on your machine, if it's not:

```
sudo apt-get install whois
```